# Unable to get Facebook Login Activity to work

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am working on a small app that makes use of the Facebook SDK (v3.6). After much effort, I was able make an activity named FBLoginActivity (with parent MainActivity) that makes use of the code I borrowed from the samples in the Facebook SDK (namely, Scrumptious). I have a button in the main activity that leads to the FBLoginActivity (it's basically a login page similar to that in Scrumptious and has a LoginButton to authenticate the user and for session control).

However, when I try running the app and click the button, the app crashes. I have imported the Facebook SDK into my workspace, all the code builds fine. On the Facebook developer page, I have added a new platform for Android in my app and marked the fields as below:

Package Name: com.example.myfbapp
Class Name: I am not sure if this should be :com.example.insultdroid.MainActivity or com.example.insultdroid.FBLoginActivity; I have tried working with both options.

I have also added the necessary permissions and app id in my manifest.

I have generated the keyhash successfully and turned the "Single Sign On" option to Yes, as shown in the developer tutorials. Where am I going wrong? Am I missing something? Why does my FBLoginActivity fail to load?

Given below is the code for FBLoginActivity:

```
package com.example.myfbapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;


public class FBLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY = "user_skipped_login";

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS +1;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
    private MenuItem settings;
    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private boolean userSkippedLogin = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            userSkippedLogin = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY);
        }
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SplashFragment splashFragment = (SplashFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SPLASH] = splashFragment;
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        //fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();

        splashFragment.setSkipLoginCallback(new SplashFragment.SkipLoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSkipLoginPressed() {
                userSkippedLogin = true;
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;

        // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising reporting.  Do so in
        // the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY, userSkippedLogin);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open, try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            userSkippedLogin = false;
        } else if (userSkippedLogin) {
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen and ask the user to login, unless the user explicitly skipped.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(settings)) {
            showSettingsFragment();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void showSettingsFragment() {
        showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            // check for the OPENED state instead of session.isOpened() since for the
            // OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED state, the selection fragment should already be showing.
            if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED)) {
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfbapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/angry_android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfbapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfbapp.FavLogActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fav_log" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfbapp.FBLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fblogin"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfbapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfbapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.example.myfbapp.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me!
This is the error Logcat:

```
01-12 17:34:35.478: D/dalvikvm(7010): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 2% free 9090K/9196K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
01-12 17:34:35.518: I/dalvikvm-heap(7010): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.726MB for 16588816-byte allocation
01-12 17:34:35.538: D/dalvikvm(7010): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 25289K/25400K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-12 17:34:35.808: I/TextToSpeech(7010): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
01-12 17:34:35.848: I/Adreno-EGL(7010): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
01-12 17:34:35.878: D/OpenGLRenderer(7010): Enabling debug mode 0
01-12 17:34:38.381: D/AndroidRuntime(7010): Shutting down VM
01-12 17:34:38.381: W/dalvikvm(7010): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ccba8)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010): Process: com.example.myfbapp, PID: 7010
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfbapp/com.example.myfbapp.FBLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:227)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:212)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(UiLifecycleHelper.java:87)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at com.example.myfbapp.FBLoginActivity.onCreate(FBLoginActivity.java:48)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-12 17:34:38.381: E/AndroidRuntime(7010):     ... 11 more
01-12 17:34:40.713: I/Process(7010): Sending signal. PID: 7010 SIG: 9
```

Hope this helps!

I do not understand this bit of code in Scrumptious's manifest. I do not have this code in my manifest. What is it and is it required?

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider233936543368280"
                  android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" />
```

"233936543368280" is the appid for Scrumptious.

Comment: can u post the error logcat?

Comment: I have added the error logcat. Does that help?

Comment: check applpicaqtion id Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null

Comment: my app id is not null. I already checked that bit when I read the logs, I have a "app_id" field in my strings.xml with the valid app id. Then why isn't the program able to read the app id?

Comment: Also, what should the Class Name be on the developer page? Should it be com.example.myfbapp.MainActivity or com.example.myfbapp.FBLoginActivity?

Comment: try <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/APP_ID"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the app id manifest with this:

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Comment: Oh, will try that! I thought it had to be my package name. Also, can you answer my question for the Class Name on the developer page?

Comment: the class name on the dev page should be the class that call for first the facebook API

Comment: so I have a button in the MainActivity which then calls the FBLoginActivity class. It is this class that makes all the Facebook sdk calls. So should it be this class that has to be mentioned on the dev page?

Comment: Well it still doesn't work even though I think the appId error is now resolved. Thanks! This is the new logcat output: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37055351/log2.txt Please have a look into this :)

Comment: You have problem here : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment"

Comment: Yea i got the problem thanks! I was doing many thing incorrectly, will have to put up a different question now!